# Deny php script to access parent directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created an online php compiler. The problem is that it makes my server vulnerable to the hackers. So i want to give the compiler a separate directory and restrict php script access to that directory only.
I have tried this

```
<Directory /parentDirectory/childDirectoryOne>
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/parentDirectory/childDirectoryOne"
</Directory>
```

But this created another problem. I was no longer able to open than page of website. It gave me internal server error.
If I can restrict php to read, edit or delete files outside the directory that will also work or if I can restrict php to read, edit or delete all files with one exception.
I have cpanel for website so I can only do that through .htaccess.

Comment: `.htaccess` files contain directives for the web-server, it does not restrict php in any way so you can still include, display and execute whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done at the operating system level. Create a new user and only give them access to the coding directory and launch the PHP process as that user.

But your code is wrong `open_basedir "/parentDirectory/subDir"` means even the PHP engine executing your index.php script can not run if it isn't in subDir. You could static code the parentDirectory or use my solution above. Storing open_basedir value in an apache file does not prevent execution by PHP-CLI or the command line.

Comment: Thanks @Zack but I don't know how to do that in cpanel. I have a shared Godaddy hosting account. Can we please tell me how to do that in Cpanel using .htaccess. I got that code from stack overflow if you can help me with the right code